# indexOf parentheses closing

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, indexof

This line of code is incorrectly closing the wrong brackets.

```
if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
```

The code displays the bracket as if it is a valid string but when I check the opening and closing braces it's thinking that (') is a bracket pair when (')') should be the bracket pair.

Is this line actually valid? Atom's mixed signals are confusing me.

**Editor view of parenthesis #1**:

[image: editor view of parenthesis #1]

**Editor view of parenthesis #2**:

[image: editor view of parenthesis #2]

Comment: <rant>why are you doing an assignment in an if? Writing code like that is just bug prone.</rant>

Comment: Is it the browser or IDE with the issue? The code is valid.

Comment: Are you referring to `Atom` as in the editor? Is it `Atom` that thinks that `(')` is matching parenthesis? Because that line is valid javascript. Not a pretty one but still valid.

Comment: @Saj: After your edit: Take it up with the developers of `Atom`. This is something SO can't answer.

Comment: File a bug report with the editor

Comment: Thank you everyone - I'll let Atom know

Answer (score -1):

If your code does not throw a syntax error, any highlighting/folding/matching issues in the editor may be just editor bugs. Maybe it is worth to post them to the editor bug tracker.

Comment: Ah okay, the entire code isn't running as expected so seeing if it was a matching issue was my first guess.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have unbalanced parentheses, your code does not even start running, it fails on parsing stage with a syntax error message.

Answer (score -3):

So simple, just escape the problematic character using `\`. Also for the better reading experience of the code, I would do it like this:

Note:
Instead of `!=` you should use `!==`, `indexOf` will allways return a number.

```
let toCheck = "\)";
let ix = version.indexOf(toCheck);
if (ix !== -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
```